# Update panels / timers

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have one huge update panel that covers my whole page (Which is a table). The problem is in this table, each cell has another table in it which stores data and displays it. I already made my huge update panel cover the larger table, but how can I add in an update panel to the smaller tables? Thanks! The reason I Need this is because each column has different data that needs to be updated at different times! Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how can I add in an update panel to the smaller tables?

An `UpdatePanel`s can be nested without a problem. If you don't want the outer one to be updated make the `UpdateMode` of the inner panel `Conditional`.

However, I would also recommend moving away from `UpdatePanel`s altogether and using jQuery/Json directly - you'll be able to make more efficient (less data and updating) web pages.

Comment: Okay, But how do I make the update panel cover a whole table, I can only seem to get it to cover a cell? @Joe R. And thanks for the advice, i'll look into that when I Have a chance